# AVIReader in AForge

Tags: c#, .net, video, aforge

I am trying to read all frames from a video I write this code but getting an unhandled exception

```
AVIReader reader = new AVIReader();
reader.Open("drop.avi");
while (reader.Position - reader.Start < reader.Length)
{
    Bitmap image = reader.GetNextFrame();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I am having the same issue. When I used AVIWriter i used the wmv3 codec, but the AVIReader cant seem to handle that codec. Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the build of your application to a X86 Machine
Go to

```
BUILD->CONFIGURATION MANAGER->CHANGE TO X86 PLATFORM
```

Or try changing the CODEC's